# Why does struct.unpack need 2 extra bytes?

Tags: python, struct

I have the following `struct.unpack` call that fails:

```
struct.unpack('14x4x2i2xh8x2i', b'\0'*46)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#88>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.unpack('14x4x2i2xh8x2i', b'\0'*46)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 48 bytes
```

I've added up the number of bytes required by the format multiple times, and I always come up with a total of 46 bytes.  But obviously the error says it's not enough.  Why am I coming up short?

The following does produce the expected output:

```
struct.unpack('14x4x2i2xh8x2i', b'\0'*48)

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Integers have to be aligned at 4-byte boundaries. So there are 2 bytes of padding before `2i`.

Comment: @Barmar that deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @Barmar and that's unfortunate for me, because I don't have any control over the structure that's being unpacked.  It's a Microsoft BMP file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `struct` expects types to be aligned. Since `i` is 4 bytes, it's 2 bytes of padding are assumed to get the offset to a multiple of 4.

You can use the `=` flag at the beginning of the format string to indicate that values are packed rather than aligned.

```
struct.unpack('=14x4x2i2xh8x2i', b'\0'*46)
```

See the documentation of [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). You should probably actually use `<` rather than `=`, since BMP integers are stored in little-endian format.

Comment: I looked right at that table as I was putting together the format string, figured since I was on a PC the default "native" would be good enough. Didn't even notice the Alignment column!